# Mod_rewrite // $_GET['var'] not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm trying to rewrite the links of a website from https://www.izloud.com/index.php?p=login (and others like https://www.izloud.com/index.php?p=login&sub=error_1)

Rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&sub=$2 [L]
```

And I want to still get the variables `$_GET['p'] && $_GET['sub']` from the link.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `[QSA]` modifier, see [Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).